# Mouse Trail using the default pointer for the trail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m looking for a script that creates a mouse trail. They are several around (I know), but I would like one that is using the (browser/os) default arrow/pointer to make the trailer and not using an image. Is something like this possible? Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to create a mouse trial of a mouse with just css, for that you will have to use an image.

You can however, create a mouse trial otherwise.

`Here are some examples:`

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/mystor/pen/Bkdcm)

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UnXrw/)

Like you said, there are a lot out there.